# "Like" a Facebook page on mobile iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, mobile

Does anyone know if there is a way for a user on their iPhone to "Like" a facebook page without having to re-login via the browser every time? Everyone uses the app obviously, so is there a way for them to just one click "like" the page? Thanks in advance.

The idea would be for people to one click like the facebook page via their mobile browser without having to login again.

Comment: It's not so obvious that _everyone_ uses the app. You should add more information about your app. Is it web based, does it include Facebook integration, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has built in badges to "Like" pages. Searched a bit and found this question.
[Adding the Facebook Like Button in an iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783803/adding-the-facebook-like-button-in-an-iphone-app)

I also found this which enables single log in. [Facebook iOS Developer Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

**Update:**
I was doing some searches and realized that you can send users to the Facebook app using custom URLs. Try adding an action to a button which sends to a URL formatted like so: `fb://page/YOURPAGEID`

Comment: I'm aware this doesn't cover the part of your question where you asked for a solution that didn't require you logging in every time but it's not usually normal for a user to "Like" the a Facebook page multiple times.

Comment: Check my updated answer. I personally haven't used Facebook logins or a "Like" button in my application but using the Facebook API I'm sure that's a feature they included.

Comment: Updated my answers check it out!