# how can I add Facebook Like button in Cocoa application

Tags: facebook, cocoa

How can i add Facebook 'Like' button (with it functionality) into Cocoa application (not iOS app), like on below image?

[image]

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783803/adding-the-facebook-like-button-in-an-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

There are [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com) and [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) (for your other question) APIs. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm new in this issue, i need info to start. Thank you for your reply!