# how can i add Twitter Follow button in Cocoa application?

Tags: cocoa, twitter

How can i add Twitter 'Follow' button (with it functionality like on website) in Cocoa application (not iOS)? It looks like on below image:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I add Facebook Like button in Cocoa application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778206/how-can-i-add-facebook-like-button-in-cocoa-application) I think one question for both would've been sufficient, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a button that opens a link in a browser. I got the following code from [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2008/May/msg00054.html):

```
NSString *applicationURL = @"https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=vitaliy";
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:applicationURL]];
```