# Facebook user follow through graph api in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to do follow `facebook` user in `ios` using `graph api` or using some custom api. I prefer this link [for php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139392/how-can-i-add-follow-us-on-facebook-button-to-an-ios-app)  and [second one who has no ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293906/facebook-user-follow-through-graph-api) or last but not least [follower button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098679/how-to-program-follow-button-in-facebook-friends-list).

Please help me to follow a user in ios.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer here: [facebook graph api to get follower count of different account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119742/facebook-graph-api-to-get-follower-count-of-different-account/26122177#26122177)

This is no longer possible via the Graph API >= v2.0.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @tobi . I know but how can i follow user or how can i check it public or private ? please give me solution.

Comment: Read my anser: **IT'S NOT POSSIBLE.**