# How do I make a like (fb) button when I click on a specific button of

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Pls  refer to my sample iphone app screen.
How would I able to like a specific fanpage when I click this button?

any suggestions? using webviews like this [Adding the Facebook Like Button in an iPhone App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783803/adding-the-facebook-like-button-in-an-iphone-app)
 I think is too complex.. is there an easy step to do this?
thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not like a fanpage using Graph API by making a customized button.

If you read the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.likes/) for the same-

> The og.likes action can refer to any open graph object or URL, except for Facebook Pages or Photos.

Also,

> For Facebook Pages or websites that do not integrate with Facebook Authentication, developers should continue to use the [Like button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) social plugin.

So in order to avoid unintentional likes on the facebook pages, facebook don't allow you this. The only option is to add a facebook's like button in order to like a facebook page.

Comment: thanks! ill try this later. hopefully I can understand this :)